# What is the Excel formula for add two years (2 Year ,10 Months, 23 Day and 2 Year ,10 Months, 6 Day)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to calculate the Sum of below the 2 values in excel

2 Year ,10 Months, 23 Day
2 Year ,10 Months, 6 Day

---

The answer is 5 year 8 months 29 day.
what is the formula for calculate.

I want to calculate the Sum of below the 2 values in excel.

2 Year ,10 Months, 23 Day
2 Year ,10 Months, 6 Day

The answer is 5 year 8 months 29 day.
what is the formula for calculate.

Comment: convert to days, add then re-convert to years, months days.

Comment: Also why `5 year 8 months 29 day` and not `5 year 9 months 1 day` or `5 year 9 months`. Feb can have 28 or 29 days and it qualifies to be a month...

Comment: Check out how Excel deals with dates, serial number where an increase of 1 is equivalent to 1 day.

Comment: How to convert days and then reconvert. Can you pls help me on this?

Comment: 1. 08-07-2010 31-05-2013 2 Year ,10 Months, 23 Day
2. 01-06-2013 07-04-2016 2 Year ,10 Months, 6 Day
In two instances, I applied the DATEDIF formula to determine the total years of experience: the first case yielded 2 years, 10 months, and 23 days, while the second case resulted in 2 years, 10 months, and 6 days. Now, I'm seeking to calculate the sum of these two durations, which should amount to 5 years, 8 months, and 29 days. Can you assist me with this?"

Comment: This last comment is more like a question by itself and more focussed than your initial question. Please post this as a new question including your actual attempt.

Answer (score 0):

So, as one comment showed it comes out to:

[image]

And the 05 as the year is because dates are counted from 1900.